# Double click on SSIS package not loading

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, dtexec

I've migrated from Visual Studio & SQL Server 2012 to 2022, and in the new server when I want to run a dtsx package manually I have to specify which one I want to run (even when double clicking on it).

How can I do as in the old version to click and automatically loads the configuration of the clicked package?

I don't want to load them using a job or directly from the catalog as these are very specified packages I have on my desktop.

When I click on the dtsx file I see this, empty.

[image: this is what I see]